# NodeMailer Parser - Convert Parsed Content to file

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

[image]I have parsed the attachment from the email which is a jpeg image, now i want to convert that content back to image and save it. Find the data i have in the attached image

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have the data. Now i just don't know how to save/convert the contents back to a file and save it. Do i need something related to file stream?

Comment: The `content` seems to be a buffer and `fs.writeFile` happens to accept a buffer. See the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)